# java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService#submit taking a long time

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-ec2, concurrency, garbage-collection

I have a very strange situation which i can't get my head around. I have defined a thread pool and its usage like this

```
      ExecutorService fixedThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
      ....some code.....
      logger.info("Event:{}, message:[{}]", Event.MESSAGE.name(), message);
      fixedThreadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          ...some code...
        }
      });
      logger.info("Submitted: Event:{}, message:[{}]", Event.MESSAGE.name(), message);
```

Now here is my output for the log messages

```
2017-07-25 20:44:41,020 [New I/O worker #1] XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXServiceImpl - Event:MESSAGE, message:[{"delegateTaskId":"_5ejQ7gtTXyfh6qnPrUeJg","sync":true,"accountId":"kmpySmUISimoRrJL6NL73w"}] 
2017-07-25 20:45:42,356 [New I/O worker #1] XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXServiceImpl - Submitted: Event:MESSAGE, message:[{"delegateTaskId":"_5ejQ7gtTXyfh6qnPrUeJg","sync":true,"accountId":"kmpySmUISimoRrJL6NL73w"}]
```

See the timestamp of the two messages. Although i am expecting that submitting to the queue for thread pool should be immediate, **it takes almost a minute between the two messages**. I have tried to eliminate all possibilities like printing GC logs (no major GC with pauses), load pattern etc.

At the time when i see this there is no load on the system and CPU use is minimal. Its running on amazon **EC2 T2LARGE** box and i can see that there is not much CPU usage.

I read java docs and google around but i couldn't find anything helpful. This is very puzzling. Any pointer is greatly appreciated.

------EDIT-----

I added the time in the log message to make sure that there is no issue of logging. The updated code is

```
logger.info("Event:{}, time:{}, message:[{}]", Event.MESSAGE.name(), new Date(), message);
fixedThreadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          ...some code...
        }
      });
logger.info("Submitted: Event:{}, time:{}, message:[{}]", Event.MESSAGE.name(), new Date(), message);
```

Here is the output

```
Event:MESSAGE, time:Wed Jul 26 17:50:18 UTC 2017, message:[{"delegateTaskId":"pN7UzXfzSWajjJY33LbM1A","sync":true,"accountId":"kmpySmUISimoRrJL6NL73w"}] 
Submitted: Event:MESSAGE, time:Wed Jul 26 17:51:19 UTC 2017, message:[{"delegateTaskId":"pN7UzXfzSWajjJY33LbM1A","sync":true,"accountId":"kmpySmUISimoRrJL6NL73w"}]
```

As you can see that the time taken to submit the task in the thread pool is almost a minute

Comment: the time stamp is created by the logger which looks like is running in a thread itself. There might be some sync or io delays. Can you add a time stamp in the message itself?

Comment: From above description not clear the exact cause of the issue  ,Can you use a  profiler  and check if you get any clue.

Comment: What is the time delta between the first logged message you showed above, and a log message in the `run` call of your Thread?

Comment: The code that is causing this slow down is not being shown in your question. You will need to include additional code for us to be able to diagnose your problem.

Comment: @SeanBright there is no additional code between the first log line and the submit call

Comment: I'm not suggesting that there is. There is something else going on in your process that is causing the behavior you are seeing. Without seeing additional code, there is no way to help you without guessing. Run the code from my answer below and tell us if you have the same results.

Comment: sure, thanks, appreciate your help

Comment: @RaghvendraSingh, what was the result when you ran the code from my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the following code, also on an AWS EC2 t2.large instance:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class RaghvendraSinghTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws Exception
    {
        ExecutorService fixedThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

        System.out.printf("[%s] Before fixedThreadPool.submit()%n", Instant.now());

        fixedThreadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.printf("[%s] In run()%n", Instant.now());
            }
        });

        System.out.printf("[%s] After fixedThreadPool.submit()%n", Instant.now());

        fixedThreadPool.shutdown();
        fixedThreadPool.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        System.out.printf("[%s] After fixedThreadPool.shutdown()%n", Instant.now());
    }
}
```

Running the code results in the following output:

```
[2017-07-26T20:11:56.730Z] Before fixedThreadPool.submit()
[2017-07-26T20:11:56.803Z] After fixedThreadPool.submit()
[2017-07-26T20:11:56.803Z] In run()
[2017-07-26T20:11:56.804Z] After fixedThreadPool.shutdown()
```

Which shows that the entire run of the program takes less than 75ms. One thing about your question that stands out to me is the name of your thread - "New I/O worker #1" - which indicates to me that there are multiple `ExecutorService`s at play here.

If you run the code I have included - and just the code I have included - do you see results similar to mine? If you do (and I suspect that you will), you should include enough code so that we can replicate your problem. Otherwise this certainly appears to be specific to your environment.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. We have the following in our logback.xml

```
<appender name="SYSLOG-TLS" class="software.wings.logging.CloudBeesSyslogAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <pattern>%date{ISO8601} %boldGreen(${process_id}) %boldCyan(${version}) %green([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %cyan(%logger) - %msg %n</pattern>
    </layout>

    <host>XXXXXXXX</host>
    <port>XXXXXXXX</port>
    <programName>XXXXXXXXX</programName>
    <key>XXXXXXXXXXX</key>
    <threshold>TRACE</threshold>
</appender>
```

This configuration made the logger.info call to post the log in logdna and the way our system was configured, the posting of the log to logdna server was synchronous and sometimes it was taking upto 60 secs and our tasks were timing out.

Now need to figure out why these logdna log posting calls are synchronous.